# How can I handle a `touchend` event triggered by scrolling vs. tapping on a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a simple list with `div`s (on iOS). I use the `touchend` event on the list elements in order execute actions. I do this because the `click` event has a ~500ms delay, which makes the UI feel sluggish.

However, the `touchend` event also fires when I scroll the list. Is there any way I can prevent the `touchend` from firing when I scroll the list, or otherwise detect if it was caused by scrolling the list? jQuery solutions are welcome.

Comment: it is a bit hard to tell what you really want. You do realize that in order to scroll, you need to swipe the screen and that will trigger `touchstart`/`touchmove`/`touchend` events, right?

Comment: Correct, I'm aware that those events are called. It works if just use the click event but then there's the delay issue (~500ms until the click event gets fired).

Comment: Now I'm confused. What type of app are you working on? is it a desktop web app or a mobile site? It would be best to give more details and maybe some demo code (a jsfiddle would do).

Comment: Could you post the code here that you have tried?

Comment: Tried the `tap` (jQuery) event?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solve it with tappy plugin: [tappy plugin](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy)

just use the 'tap' event.